# Value is multiplied when shouldn't

Tags: t-sql

I've got such query

```
select
D.Name
,C.ClientId
,C.SetId
,C.CaseId
,C.ClientCaseNumber
,sum(DD.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]
,sum(PDH.Capital) as [Capital] 
,sum(PDH.Other) as [Other]
,sum(PDH.InterestsU) as [InterestsU]
,PH.AccountType
,sum(PDH.Overpayment) as [Overpayment]
,PROV.ProvisionValue
,PH.OpDate
,C.DateImported
FROM CaseDetails as C
join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PH on C.CaseDetailsId = PH.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentDocumentHistory as PDH on PH.PaymentId = PDH.PaymentCaseHistoryId
join ClientProvision as PROV on C.ProductId = PROV.ClientProductId
join DocumentDetails as DD on C.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId

WHERE (PH.IsDeleted is NULL or PH.IsDeleted <> 'True') and C.ProductId = PROV.ClientProductId and C.ClientId= '2'
GROUP by D.Name, C.ClientId, C.CaseId, C.SetId, C.ClientCaseNumber,  PH.AccountType, PDH.Overpayment, PH.OpDate, C.DateImported, PROV.ProvisionValue
ORDER by PH.OpDate
```

Problem is: in few results (when there is more than 1 Document connected with case) is multiplied by the number of the documents.

Example:

Case has 3 documents, when User is adding a payment connected with case the value is spread on all the documents till 0.

Capital of case is 6100 however result shows 18300.
Capital payed should be shown as 4372,03 however shows 13116,09 
etc.

Probably I made a mistake somewhere in "GROUP BY" section.

The query should work like this: sum a total Capital, Overpayments etc etc by case, so even if case has few documents show only 1 result of sums.

Comment: Have you considered dividing multiplied results by count()?

Comment: Thought about this but I treat it as "final solution" when nothing else would like to work.

Comment: Considering your data model, I think you have to make selection between using two queries or using count

Comment: Do you have any other links between entities? I count 4 different 1-to-many relationships on CaseDetails. This is very likely to result in aggregate errors like the one you encounter. If you have a relationship between DD and PDH you could only change the from part and (probably) not need subqueries.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This way of linking is the only possible between those tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you state that multiple DocumentDetails rows per CaseDetails row produces incorrect values for Capital and some other column, you could get most of the data in a subquery and join the DocumentDetails table in the outer query to get its correct sums.  By joining the DocumentDetails table after all the other sums/grouping is performed, you ensure that each DocumentDetails row joined to the subquery's result set will not be multipled by the other joining tables.

```
select
sum(DD.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]
,r.Name
,r.ClientId
,r.SetId
,r.CaseId
,r.ClientCaseNumber
,r.[Capital] 
,r.[Other]
,r.[InterestsU]
,r..AccountType
,r.[Overpayment]
,r.ProvisionValue
,r.OpDate
,r.DateImported
from (
    select
    D.Name
    ,C.ClientId
    ,C.SetId
    ,C.CaseId
    ,C.ClientCaseNumber
    ,sum(PDH.Capital) as [Capital] 
    ,sum(PDH.Other) as [Other]
    ,sum(PDH.InterestsU) as [InterestsU]
    ,PH.AccountType
    ,sum(PDH.Overpayment) as [Overpayment]
    ,PROV.ProvisionValue
    ,PH.OpDate
    ,C.DateImported
    ,C.CaseDetailsId
    FROM CaseDetails as C
    join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
    join PaymentCaseHistory as PH on C.CaseDetailsId = PH.CaseDetailsId
    join PaymentDocumentHistory as PDH on PH.PaymentId = PDH.PaymentCaseHistoryId
    join ClientProvision as PROV on C.ProductId = PROV.ClientProductId

    WHERE (PH.IsDeleted is NULL or PH.IsDeleted <> 'True') and C.ProductId = PROV.ClientProductId and C.ClientId= '2'
    GROUP by D.Name, C.ClientId, C.CaseId, C.SetId, C.ClientCaseNumber,  PH.AccountType, PDH.Overpayment, PH.OpDate, C.DateImported, PROV.ProvisionValue
     ) r
join DocumentDetails as DD on r.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId
ORDER by r.OpDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the join to DocumentDetails and replace

`sum(DD.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]`

with

`(select sum(DD.TransferedCapital) 
    from CaseDetails CDD
    inner join DocumentDetails as DD on DD.CaseDetailsId = CDD.CaseDetailsId
    where C.CaseID = CDD.CaseID) as [TransferedCapital]`

A condition `where DD.CaseDetailsID = C.CaseDetailsID` here is not possible inside this subquery because C.CaseDetailsID isn't in the grouping. CaseID is. Change this id if you want a total on a different level.